# Show "Related" posts by the person asking the question

Tags: feature-request, related-questions

As I've gotten more into reviewing and looking at questions, especially by those fairly new to Stack Overflow, I noticed that a poorly worded question that gets ignored will often be asked again by the same user, or asked again in a slightly different way while contextually being the same.

For those who have the review tools available to them, I think it would be great if in the side-right bar it would display **Related by User** above the current **Related** listing. Using the same algorithm Stack currently uses, drill it down to only posts by that person asking the question. This way, at quick glance, we can determine if the user is posting duplicates, as often happens with new users.

Comment: Yes please. Many times have I started in on a comment thread trying to draw better information out of an OP, to find duplicate CVs rolling in because the OP already asked the same thing a half hour earlier that I didn't see.